# How to know if the installation of Windows updates has been frozen or still working?

Tags: windows-7, windows-update, updates

I had a fresh install of Windows 7. Now it downloaded lots of updates and installing it when I shutdown yesterday. Namely 158 updates.

Now at the morning it's at the 138th one, and apparently stuck.

Is there any visual indicator that tells me it actually working on something? I guess the throbbers are not reliable.

Comment: No; There besides the count; there is no visual progress bar.  Even if there was, it wouldn't be enabled, so you would have to still wait.

Answer (score 0):

No visual indicator other than hard drive activity. If there is none, it's probably hung or waiting for input. Hard for us to know exactly what it going on with your particular system.

Sometimes Windows Update is waiting for a reboot to install some of the updates (even thought there isn't a message). I've seen this in the past. After rebooting, the updates continue prior to Windows loading. Then finishes once it gets to the desktop.

You should be able to view the update history to see what updates failed. They should automatically attempt to install again.

Answer (score 0):

You got any recovery drive? If so try hard shut down.Then check whether updates are being installed or not? If not try updating and see if the all the 137 have been downloaded.